# how to create virtual router/switch on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, ipv6, interface

I have a dedicated server ubuntu 16.04 OS / 8 GB Ram, with over 5000 IPv6 from /48 subnet assigned to using below command

```
ip -6 addr add IPv6/48 dev eth0
```

creating massive parllel connections cycling between these different IPs each run for my crawling project,

problem is server provider messaged me about high load on the switch, that affects other users on the device

and the only solution would be create a virtual router/switch on server that we can direct route the entire /48

Any help ?

Edit1:
i assigned ipv6 to lo interface using

```
ip -6 addr add IPv6/48 dev lo
```

It's working perfectly, Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/features/)? Seems exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] high load on the switch [...] that we can direct route the entire /48

Reading between the lines, the only thing I can think of that they could possibly have in mind is IPv6 neighbour discovery table overload. If this is what they are thinking about, then they can indeed direct route the whole /48 to you and this will be better and easier for both you and them.

I can't think of any possible reason you would need to create anything resembling a "a virtual router/switch" though. If the /48 were directly routed to you then you could just add all your IP addresses to, say, `lo` instead of `eth0`, and everything should work.

```
ip addr add IPv6/48 dev lo
```